# There is way to re-use a variable into a select new{ }?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the next code:

```
var object = 
     (from result in ListOfINFO
      group result by result.Name into grp
      orderby grp.Key
      select new
      {
          Name = grp.Key,                                          
          KM=grp.Sum(s=>s.KM),                                    
          Gasoline=grp.Where(w => w.Gasoline != "NaN").Sum(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Gasoline)),
          //Use=KM/Gasoline,//<=Something like that I want
      }).ToList();
```

I wanna calculate "Use" with the previous variables "KM" and  "Gasoline" to not repeat all the operation, but I cannot use them.  I dont know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: you would have to do it in another pass through your list. But what's to stop you doing Use=(grp.Sum(s=>s.KM)/grp.Where(w => w.Gasoline != "NaN").Sum(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Gasoline)))?

Comment: I have another cases when the expresion is longer than this, and I have to repit it many times